# MySql Database Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Hello i can't save to my database it says that i have a syntax error with my database. And what data type should i use into my Number column i will input 11 digit mobile number.

[this is the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTKuM.jpg)

[This is my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s436W.jpg)

and here are the codes

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports System.Data.Sql
Imports System
Imports System.Data

Public Class AddStudent
Dim connString As String = "server=localhost;userid=jared;password=jared;database=database;persistsecurityinfo=True"
Dim SQLConnection As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection
Dim scitech As New DataTable()

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim iReturn As Boolean
    Using SQLConnection As New MySqlConnection(connString)
        Using sqlCommand As New MySqlCommand()
            With sqlCommand
                .CommandText = "INSERT INTO scitech ('name', 'Surname', 'Number', 'College', 'Course', 'Year') values (@sName,@sLname,@sNum,@sCollege,@sCourse,@sYr)"
                .Connection = SQLConnection
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@sName", TextBox1name.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@sLname", TextBox2su.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@sNum", TextBox3num.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@sCollege", ComboBox1.SelectedItem)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@sCourse", ComboBox2.SelectedItem)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@sYr", ComboBox3.SelectedItem)
            End With
            Try
                SQLConnection.Open()
                sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                iReturn = True
            Catch ex As MySqlException
                MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
                iReturn = False
            Finally
                SQLConnection.Close()
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
    InsertStud()
End Sub

Public Function InsertStud() As Boolean

    Dim iReturn As Boolean
    Using SQLConnection As New MySqlConnection(connString)
        Using sqlCommand As New MySqlCommand()
            With sqlCommand
                .CommandText = "INSERT INTO database.scitech ('name', 'Surname', 'Number', 'College', 'Course', 'Year') values (@sName,@sLname,@sNum,@sCollege,@sCourse,@sYr)"
                .Connection = SQLConnection
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@sName", TextBox1name.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@sLname", TextBox2su.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@sNum", TextBox3num.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@sCollege", ComboBox1.SelectedItem)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@sCourse", ComboBox2.SelectedItem)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@sYr", ComboBox3.SelectedItem)
            End With
            Try
                SQLConnection.Open()
                sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                iReturn = True
            Catch ex As MySqlException
                MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
                iReturn = False
            Finally
                SQLConnection.Close()
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
    Return iReturn
End Function
```

Comment: I don't see 'name' in your table definition.

Comment: can you post the entire SQL query here? @Mort the name filed is hidden, the scrollbar is moved

Comment: Try removing the quotes at insert: "INSERT INTO scitech (name, Surname, Number, College, Course, Year)

Comment: You are using single quotes around columns names.  Remove the single quotes.  In fact, only use single quotes for string and date/time constants.  I vote to close this type of question as a typographical error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have **name** defined in your table, and try removing the apostrphes around your column names.

Answer (score 0):

You are using ' instead of ` for fields names.
The single quote ' is only for values strings